# How to handle dynamically generated checkbox in selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click number of checkbox which is generated dynamically.
How to perform that task? please help.
Given Below is the Xpath sequence of the checkbox

```
//*[@id="220077552"]/td[1]/app-checkbox/label

//*[@id="220219925"]/td[1]/app-checkbox/label

//*[@id="220077552"]/td[1]/app-checkbox/label
```

each time this id is generated automatically. 
What should be used to find the element?

I tried this code below

```
 WaitUtils.waitForDataToLoad(getDriver());
        List<WebElement> memberSelection = getDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector(".form-checkbox.notext"));
        for(int count =1;  count<=10; count++){
            memberSelection.get(count).click();
        }
```

Comment: Did you try anything? If you did post your code and explain what was the problem with it.

Comment: Hello, please attach html and code samples. We cannot guess what you have done so far!

Comment: @Guy  I have posted the code I tried

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of XPath functions like `starts-with`, `contains` or `ends-with`.

Sample code looks like:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, '220')]
```